# How to Convert Date to Thai

Tags: translation, date, language

The Thai text I want to end up with is: อาทิตย์ 03 มกราคม 2016 to อาทิตย์ ๐๓ มกราคม ๒๐๑๖

I don't think it should matter what language but in this case it is Thai.

My function is:

```
$strdate = get_thai_date();
print_r($strdate["number"]);
```

And the output is:

```
Array (
  [0] => ๐ 

  [1] => ๑

  [2] => ๒ 

  [3] => ๓

  [4] => ๔

  [5] => ๕

  [6] => ๖

  [7] => ๗

  [8] => ๘

  [9] => ๙
)
```

The input is `sunday 03 january 2016` and I am trying to return `อาทิตย์ 03 มกราคม 2016`, but not `อาทิตย์ ๐๓ มกราคม ๒๐๑๖`.

Would a function like `preg_replace()`, `strstr()` or something else work? Can someone provide an examples?

Comment: There's no `get_thai_date` function in WordPress or in PHP, where is this function coming from and how is it implemented? the same goes for the other variations you mentioned, they're not a part of standard WordPress

Comment: I made get_thai_date(). In functions.php: function get_thai_date() {...}

Comment: @Dani Can you edit your question to include the code where you wrote the `get_thai_date()` function please?

Comment: setlocale(LC_TIME, "th_TH.UTF-8");
        echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y", strtotime(get_the_date()));

        $strdate = get_thai_date();
        print_r($strdate["number"]);

        //preg, strstr or others. What to do?

Comment: function get_thai_date() {
  $strdate = array (
    "number" => array("๐", "๑", "๒", "๓", "๔", "๕", "๖", "๗", "๘", "๙"),
    //...
  )
}   

output
     Array ( [0] => ๐ [1] => ๑ [2] => ๒ [3] => ๓ [4] => ๔ [5] => ๕ [6] => ๖ [7] => ๗ [8] => ๘ [9] => ๙ )

Comment: Dani, do you have the wordpress thai localisation pack included in your website?  translations etc?  WP does this stuff.  use date_i18n as per https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

Comment: Delete $strdate = get_thai_date();, and add sometimes like date_i18n()? Hmmm I don't know.

Comment: @Dani you can edit your question to include the `get_thai_date` function, and include a full version not a cut down version. The very in your comment is unreadable

Comment: Okay, function get_thai_date() { $strdate = array ( "number" => array("๐", "๑", "๒", "๓", "๔", "๕", "๖", "๗", "๘", "๙") ) }; 
Removing "//...". And it still sais Array ( [0] => ๐ [1] => ๑ [2] => ๒ [3] => ๓ [4] => ๔ [5] => ๕ [6] => ๖ [7] => ๗ [8] => ๘ [9] => ๙ ) .

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "th_TH.UTF-8");
echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y", strtotime(get_the_date()));
```

Before: อาทิตย์ 03 มกราคม 2016

```
//$strdate = get_thai_date();
//print_r($strdate["number"]); //preg, strstr or others.

//$strdate = date_i18n(...);
```

After: อาทิตย์ ๐๓ มกราคม ๒๐๑๖

Comment: Got it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766726/convert-persian-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers